# SQL Server 2008 CrossTab equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Afternoon Guys n Girls.

Using SQL SERVER 2008.

I have a table called **userModList**.  Its contains fields, "**USERID**"(int), "**ModuleID**"(int), and "**Passed**"(bin).
example data;

```
USERID    ModuleID    Passed
134         12          1
134         10          0
134         18          1
```

What i would like to display is:

```
USERID    (moduleNum12)     (ModuleNum10)     (ModuleNum18)
 134           1                  0                 1
```

Now In MS access all you would do is create a **cross query**,  so User ID becomes the **row**,  Module numbers become the **Columns** and Passed is the **values** (binary 1 or 0).

I would like to do this server Side in a Stored Procedure, but I have never Attempted cross tabbing data.

Also The **moduleID is dynamic** meaning there may be 3 modules for a user or 17.  So it needs to be dynamic, not sure if this makes a big difference?

Anyway some help on this would be great, ill try and provide some sample code Of what I will try, But as it stands I'm stuck as to where to start.

many thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can do this in SQL Server you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select userid,
  [12] moduleNum12,
  [10] moduleNum10,
  [18] moduleNum18
from
(
  select userid, moduleid, cast(passed as int) passed
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(passed)
  for moduleId in ([12], [10], [18])
) piv;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89e33/1)

Or you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select userid,
  max(case when moduleid = 12 then cast(passed as int) end) moduleNum12,
  max(case when moduleid = 10 then cast(passed as int) end) moduleNum10,
  max(case when moduleid = 18 then cast(passed as int) end) moduleNum18
from yourtable
group by userid;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89e33/3).

The above work great if the values are known nut if you have unknown values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsAlias AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ModuleID) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsAlias = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(ModuleID) +' as moduleNum'+cast(ModuleID as varchar(10))
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT userid,' + @colsAlias + ' 
            from
            (
               select userid, moduleid, cast(passed as int) passed
               from yourtable 
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                max(passed)
                for moduleid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89e33/5)

Comment: thats what i was looking into, but the "in" method expects you too know how many modules.  Unfortunately that part needs to be dynamic.  any extension on what you would do?

Comment: @StevenSmith I was in the process of adding that version. You will have to use dynamic SQL is the values are unknown.

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer bluefeet!  ill check it out know, looks scary but hopefully will solve the question.  what is "STUFF((..." just a generic name or refer to a method to use?

Comment: @StevenSmith STUFF and FOR XML PATH are used to get the list of the columns that will be used in the sql string.

Comment: just tried it, There is a problem using MAX since my "passed" column is a bit column ERROR: Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

Comment: @StevenSmith Then you will need to cast the `passed` datatype. see my edits

Comment: of course!  I was looking a for an alternative Operator for A bit value thinking "there really isnt any" totally forgot i can just cast as an int since its only a bit...doh! many thanks!